# PHP Ratchet Websocket Slowing down server

Tags: php, apache, websocket, proxypass, ratchet

it's my first time asking a question on here but this matter has me nuts and I really don't know where else to look.

I've implemented a Ratchet Websocket Server on PHP, we're not using nginx on the server, we're using apache proxy pass to handle the websocket connections.
On my application, if you are on a given page you'll get connected to the websocket, send a subscribe message (because we send data to users from one same group and we need to know which group every client comes from) and just simply wait for an update message. When someone updates data, after the PHP code that updates to the database and does whatever needs to be done, I have another connection to the websocket that just simply connects, sends an update message with the info of the group and closes the connection.

Everything works perfectly fine, but sometimes, without a given pattern, it can happen in 3 days or it can happen after 10 days, the server (usually on higher traffic times) slows down, for all clients at the same time. Though when this usually happens is during hight traffic time it isn't always, and also not always at peak traffic... when it does happen simply restarting apache makes everything go to back to normal. Resources seem fine at these times also, nothing ever gets higher than 15% usage...

I'm not very well known in Apache config and neither is my partner so the configuration we have is whatever is default for Apache, we're looking into setting up our own custom configuration.

With what has happened we can say this is in some way the websockets fault, because before trying the apache restart we would just remove all websocket connection code and it would get stable again, so it seems it does somehow come from the websocket. The only error we're getting  from logs relevant to this is that when the slow down starts websocket connection timeouts are being logged.

```
WebSocket connection failed: Connection to tls://www.mysite.es:443 timed out after 20 seconds (ETIMEDOUT)
```

Other than this we don't see anything...

Our SocketMaster also doesn't do any database connections or heavy workload, we just store in objects the group and client connection and when an update message arrives we check 2 of these objects to get the info to who to send the message and loop through a given object to send said messages (these objects per group are up until now never of more than 6 in size).

Has anyone ever experienced this or have a clue as to what I could look for? Or has anyone encounter something like it or similar?